# Python cannot find package after pip install

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install `sumo` using `pip3 install --user sumo` with `Python@3.9`
However although the `sumo` package is already installed, it cannot be invoked by `which sumo`, and same problem for `which scipy` & `which numpy`

In the `site-package` folder I can find all these packages, so it is definitely properly installed by `pip3`

Edited:

```
python3 -m site

sys.path = [
    '/Users/tonyspc',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/tonyspc/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/sip/6.1.1/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/tonyspc/Library/Python/3.9' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/tonyspc/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

My current `PATH` for `Python3` and `pip3` is:

```
which python3 
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3

which pip3
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/pip3
```

I searched a little bit for solutions on the internet, none of them solved this issue.

1.I changed the environment variables for in the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` and sourced it

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/"
```

2.I changed file permission and attributes for `site-packages` folder

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
```

3.I tried uninstall and reinstall `Python@3.9` with `Homebrew`, still won't help

4.I tried uninstall and reinstall packages with `pip3 install --user` and `Python3 -m pip install --user`, still nothing changes.

Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Comment: For sanity; always use `python3 -m pip`, since you can never be user what version of python `pip3` is associated with.

Comment: Show the output of `python3 -m site`.  Does the user site exist, and is it enabled?

Comment: `pip install --user` should have installed files somewhere in your home directory, which you didn't add to your `PATH`.

Comment: If you're using multiple python versions, I'd recommend using something like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to ensure you're using the right python/pip. Also, please post the output of the `pip install` - wherever it installed the package, is the dir you need to add to your path

Comment: "it cannot be invoked by `which sumo`, and same problem for `which scipy` & `which numpy`" - it it _supposed_ to be invoked as a standalone executable? There's no wonder `which scipy` and `which numpy` "don't work" - you normally check whether a Python library is installed by attempting to import it _from Python_. For instance, open the interpreter and type `import numpy`. If that fails, the library isn't installed properly.

Comment: @wim Just updated it in the main post

Answer (score 2):

You cannot invoke a package that is not suposed to run as standalone in command shell.

To check if the package is correctly installed you can import inside Python

```
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sumo
```

Otherwise you can run it in a shell calling the module with the "-m" parameter.

```
python3 -m <package> <parameters>
```

Comment: `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: No module named sumo-optplot`

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://smtg-ucl.github.io/sumo/sumo-optplot.html) of sumo, you can run this as standalone command, not as module. Can you run the following and see if it's any output? `sumo-optplot -h`